# How do I get rid of this code: â€‹ that appears client side?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, syntax

When I view the source of a page I see this bit of code appear `â€‹` before `<script>` (client side) but that character doesn't appear anywhere in the php file (server side). I have tried removing all the space in the php file between `</div>` and `<script>`, but that doesn't do anything. I've also copied all this code to Notepad and then inserted it back into the PHP file, but that doesn't get rid of `â€‹` - any idea what it is and how to get rid of it?

```
<div class="btn popover-link">How to use it</div>​â€‹
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.popover-link').popover({
     html: 'true',
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: 'How to Use It',
    content: '<strong>Content</strong>',
    trigger: 'click'
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: change you application encoding, database encoding, html encoding to utf-8.

Comment: Did you copy the code from jsfiddle ? Then simply remove the invisible chars in your source files by removing a selection covering it.

Comment: Twisted is right. UTF-8 end-to-end or die.

Comment: @Twisted1919 great thanks - added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and it goes.

Comment: @MarkR21 have a read of http://kunststube.net/frontback/ too if you're not already familiar with it.

Comment: @cbuckley great article, will prove very useful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's a zero-width space character, encoded as utf-8, but output as latin1. It's got to be in your source code somewhere, but you just can't see it.

I'd suggest you select everything from the close `</div>` tag to the opening `<script>` tag, delete that selection, then type those tags in again.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your editor, but change the encoding to UTF-8 or UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: The BOM is always at the start of the file, this wouldn't remove a BOM in the middle of a document.